# Make an access directory structure tree?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

I want to run a script that will show me all the folders (output to a text file) that the running user can see starting from root, down to the point where it doesn't have the permissions to go any further.

Does anyone have a script for this?

I am running RedHat 6

Answer (score 0):

Just run `tree -d` as that user, using either `sudo -u` or `su`.

```
# sudo -u grawity tree -d /run
/run
├── dbus
├── dovecot
├── gdm [error opening dir]
├── httpd
...
```

Comment: `bash: tree: command not found`...sorry I am actually running on RedHat!

Comment: I assumed you know how to install additional software. If I remember correctly, RH uses `yum` as its package manager.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned. I want a solution where I don't have to install anything. I work in an environment where it takes forever to get anything installed - hence requesting a script.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done from the command line using:

`tree -d / > textfile.txt 2> /dev/null`

while logged into that account. This would provide a long-form directory listing recursively, write the output to `textfile.txt` and the errors to the blackhole that is `/dev/null`. If you want to keep the errors remove the `2>` redirect. If done from the root account, you can add `sudo -u <username>` to the beginning of the command to perform the task as another user. If it needs to be a script you could either just drop the command into a shell script, or if you only need to do this yourself and want ease of access, you could make an alias with the command.

Edit: Now that you've added that you're on RHEL, I know of two different ways of handling this. If you don't need to actually draw the tree structure but just want a recursive listing of directories, you can switch `tree -d` for `find / -type d -ls` or, were you to have installation priveleges, run `yum install tree`.

Comment: bash: tree: command not found...sorry I am actually running on RedHat!